# Equality of signs of eigenvalues between Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

How can one show that a matrix A, if A = PDP^T (where P^T is the transpose of P and D is a diagonal matrix), has the same eigenvectors as the matrix D? Furthermore, how does one show that the eigenvalues of the respective eigenvectors of A should have the same sign as the eigenvalues of the matrix D?

If,   Av=lv    (v an eigenvector and l the corresponding eigenvalue),

Dw=tw    (w an eigenvector an t the eigenvalue).

AP^-T=PD    (P^-T the inverse transpose)

then AP^-Tw=PDw and thus AP^-Tw=tPw.
If the initial equation were A = PDP^-1 (P^- the inverse of P) then I would have had APw=tPw and would have shown that the for every eigenvector "w" of D there is an eigenvector "Pw" of A with the same eigenvalue for "A" as "w" has for "D"... But I'm stuck at AP^-Tw=tPw...

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

Let $\lambda\in\mathbb F$ be an arbitrary eigenvalue of $A\in M_n(\mathbb F)$

We know that $\lambda I_n$ commutes with all the matrices in $M_n$ and we're going to use the following:
$$\color{red}{\lambda I=P^{-1}\lambda I P}$$
If $\color{red}{P}$ is an $\color{red}{\text{orthogonal matrix}}$, then:
$$\color{red}{\lambda I=P^{\tau}\lambda I P=P\lambda I P^{\tau}}$$

In that case a diagonal matrix is both $\color{red}{\text{upper}}$ and lower triangular matrix.

Let $k_A\in\mathbb F[\lambda]$ denote the characteristic plynomial of $A$

By the *Binet-Cauchy theorem*:

$k_{A}(\lambda)=\det(A-\lambda I)=\det\left(P^{-1}DP-\lambda I\right)=\det\left(P^{-1}(D-\lambda I) P\right)\\=\det\left(P^{-1}\right) \det(D-\lambda I) \det P=\det(D-\lambda I)=k_{D}(\lambda)$

Note: $\det$ is a scalar, so it commutes: $$\color{green}{\det A\cdot\det B=\det B\cdot\det A}$$

Similar matrices have the same characteristic polynomial and hence the same eigenvalues which are just its roots.

Comment: I'm sorry if I misunderstand but I think your reply loves the problem with A=PDP^-1, when my question was about A=PdP^T (P^T the transpose of P)

Comment: @StijnBoshoven, that can be the case with orthogonal matrices. Then $D$, which is diagonal, satisfies conditions to be called both _upper_ and _lower triangular_ matrix.

Comment: Well P is not orthogonal in general... Thanks for the responde though. I finally found the name of this theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia

Comment: It does say so. In the part with $Q$ and eigendecomposition.

Comment: Hmmm that's strange. The reason I was after this theorem is because it's used to show that the eigenvalues of the metric tensor of curved spacetime include one negative, three positive eigenvalues. In a lecture series I'm following it is said at any point in spacetime there exists a coordinate transformation that makes the spacetime locally flat. So "g = J^T n J" where J is the Jacobian of the coordinate transformation and n is the minkowski metric. It didn't mention that for the theorem to apply there must exist an orthonormal Jacobian that manages this transformation...

Comment: @StijnBoshoven, I'm also a student studying, I'll look agqin. (: